# Why is impl not in scope

Tags: generics, rust, associated-types

I'm a Rust newbie, and in my learning-toy-project I need a graph data structure with mutable nodes, so I came up with:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::clone::Clone;
use std::cmp::Eq;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub trait Constructible<T> {
    type C;
    fn new(Self::C) -> T;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct HashedGraph<K: Eq + Hash + Clone, T: Constructible<T>> {
    graph: HashMap<K, Rc<RefCell<T>>>,
}

impl<K, T> HashedGraph<K, T>
where
    K: Eq + Hash + Clone,
    T: Constructible<T>,
{
    pub fn new<C>(connections: HashMap<K, C>) -> HashedGraph<K, T> {
        let mut graph: HashMap<K, Rc<RefCell<T>>> = HashMap::new();

        for key in connections.keys() {
            graph.insert(
                key.clone(),
                Rc::new(RefCell::new(C::new(*connections.get(key).unwrap()))),
            );
        }

        HashedGraph { graph }
    }
}

impl Constructible<String> for String {
    type C = String;
    fn new(instring: String) -> String {
        instring
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut test = HashMap::new();
    test.insert("one", "ONE");
    test.insert("two", "TWO");
    let hg = HashedGraph::new(test);
}
```

The idea is, that I want the nodes to be constructible from another data type, but this data is not contained in the Graph, and therefore an associated type and not a generic parameter. The Nodes T will later contain connections, which are just weak Pointers to other nodes, but for this question that’s not really relevant. When compiling this I get an error:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `new` found for type `C` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:26:61
   |
26 |             graph.insert(key.clone(), Rc::new(RefCell::new( C::new( *connections.get(key).unwrap() ))));
   |                                                             ^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `C`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `new`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `Constructible`
```

I don't understand why the implementation of constructible is not in scope or what else is not correct. If this is an unidiomatic way of implementing this, I would be very happy to receive suggestions!

Comment: There is nothing about the `C` in `new<C>` that constrains it to `Constructable`. Also I think you can just use `Into`/`From` rather than introducing a new trait, since it looks like a conversion.

Comment: Also, implementing for `String` is probably not what you meant, since you are using `&str` in your main function.

Comment: Why does `Constructible` need an associated type? The type argument `T` seems redundant in the way you are using it, and can just be `Self`.

Answer (score 1):

In the declaration of `new<C>()`, the type parameter `C` is a new type variable with no constraints. It appears that you *intended* it to be the associated type from `T`'s `Constructible` instance, which you'd express like this:

```
pub fn new(connections: HashMap<K, T::C>) -> HashedGraph<K, T> {
 ...
}
```

Your code has a number of other problems though:

- You are instantiating the object with `&str` but you only added a `Constructible` instance for `String`. These are different types.
- You don't need to use `hashmap.get(key)` to access the value. You can just use `iter()` - or in this case `drain()`, since you are moving all of the values from one container to another anyway, so this will avoid borrowing problems if you don't need the original `HashMap`.
- `Constructible`'s type parameter is redundant. This is always going to be `Self`.
- The only way that `T` can be inferred in `fn new() -> T` is from where the caller chooses to use it. In theory, another implementation of `Constructible` could have the same associated `C` type, so that isn't enough. This means you will need type annotations when constructing the `HashedGraph`.

[Here's a version of your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4763a709899b10f0d37909d59b2f829f&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) that compiles, though I made some assumptions about what you were really trying to achieve.